# How to write simple smack 4.2.3 app that connects to server and answer to user

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I have simple smack 3.2.1 application. It connect to xmpp server
and waiting for another user conversation initiation. When user ask question
via chat, application send response (answer). And it is working fine. Here is code:

JabberApplication.java:

```
package jabberapplication;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

public class JabberApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws XMPPException,    InterruptedException {

    String username = "USERNAME";
    String password = "PASSWORD";
    String server = "SERVER";
    int port=5222;

    XmppManager xmppManager = new XmppManager(server, port);
    xmppManager.init();
    xmppManager.performLogin(username, password);
    xmppManager.setStatus(true, "Hello everyone");

    boolean isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
    xmppManager.destroy();
    }
}
```

XmppManager.java:

```
package jabberapplication;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManagerListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence.Type;

public class XmppManager {

private final String server;
private final int port;

private XMPPConnection connection;

private ChatManager chatManager;
private MessageListener messageListener;

private ConversationController conversationController;

public XmppManager(String server, int port) {
    this.server = server;
    this.port = port;
}

public void init() throws XMPPException {

    System.out.println(String.format("Initializing connection to server %1$s port %2$d", server, port));


    ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, port);
    connection = new XMPPConnection(connectionConfiguration);

    connection.connect();
    System.out.println("Connected: " + connection.isConnected());

    chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
    chatManager.addChatListener(new MyChatManagerListener());
    messageListener = new MyMessageListener();

    conversationController = new ConversationController();
}

public void performLogin(String username, String password) throws XMPPException {
    if (connection != null && connection.isConnected()) {
        connection.login(username, password);
    }
}

public void setStatus(boolean available, String status) {
    Presence.Type type = available ? Type.available : Type.unavailable;
    Presence presence = new Presence(type);
    presence.setStatus(status);
    connection.sendPacket(presence);
}

public void destroy() {
    if (connection != null && connection.isConnected()) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String message, String buddyJID) throws XMPPException {
    System.out.println(String.format("Sending mesage '%1$s' to user %2$s", message, buddyJID));
    Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(buddyJID, messageListener);
    chat.sendMessage(message);
}

class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        String from = message.getFrom();
        String body = message.getBody();
        if (!body.equals("null")) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Received message '%1$s' from %2$s", body, from));
            try {
                chat.sendMessage(conversationController.getAnswer(body));
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                 System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyChatManagerListener implements ChatManagerListener {
    @Override
    public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean bln) {
        int indexAt = chat.getParticipant().indexOf("@");
        String username = chat.getParticipant().substring(0, indexAt);
        chat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
        try {
            chat.sendMessage("Hello " + username + " !");
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Well, the question is: How to write similar app using smack library version 4.2.3. It looks like that in 4.2.3 there are no MessageListener and ChatManagerListener classes. Any suggestions ?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For Smack 4.2.3, ChatManagerListener interface is under org.jivesoftware.smack.chat class (note : chat not Chat). 
So, you need to change import to  org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatManagerListener.
Also, MessageListener is now change to ChatMessageListener also under org.jivesoftware.smack.chat class. 
So, you need to change import to org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatMessageListener.
And rename the implements to as below :
class MyMessageListener implements ChatMessageListener